# How to run migrations in a feathersjs typescript project?

Tags: typescript, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I'm wondering how to run Sequelize migrations on a typescript feathersjs project generated by feathers-plus CLI.

The guide at https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize is only concerned with JS project. TS project where sequelize migrations config created exactly according to the doc will fail with not being able to find the app module.

```
ERROR: Cannot find module '../src/app'
```

How to get it working? (I don't want to go all out Typescript on Sequelize with 3rd party typings as I smell it would bring a whole new league of issues)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a very simple way to get it working. 
Just change the extensions on the migrations/config.js and migrations/models.js files to **ts**.

So you now have migrations/config.ts and migrations/models.ts and you can run migrations in the usual way using `sequelize db:migrate`

Voilá!

Comment: did you also change in .sequellizerc?

Comment: Hm, interesting idea - but I didn't change anything there.

Comment: This worked with sequelize-cli 5.5.1, but not anymore on 6.x.x

Answer (score 0):

> migrations/config.js

change `const app = require('../src/app');` to `const app = require('../lib/app');`

after running `npm run compile`

you can now run `npx sequelize db:migrate`